# Google Play Console showing Errors, Warnings and Messages while uploading app bundle

Tags: google-play, google-play-console

When I am uploading my flutter app bundle on Play Console, it is showing some error.[image]

Dependencies used are - Firebase, Crashlytics & Analytics.
Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: It's just a warning related to debug symbols, so when crashes occur in your app in production, you get a human-readable crash report, that you can understand and fix the bugs, if you use something like crashlytics, it automatically does that for you. Otherwise, you'll have to do it yourself.

Comment: Even after using crashlytics, I am getting the warning. So is there a way to fix or avoid the warning??